# Magento order being charged twice

Tags: php, magento, payment, authorize.net

I'm a `Magento` developer, and one of my clients has been experiencing a major issue. Some of their buyers/clients (very random) are being charged twice or more the amount of their orders, yet only one order is being created each time. So far it has happened 3 times and 2 in the last 3 weeks.

They are using the `Authorize.net CIM Integration` module. After investigating a bit I realized that they were not the only Magento e-commerce site experiencing this issue. As it's nearly impossible to reproduce the error and there is no pattern, most people seem to believe it could only mean there is a downtime, timeout or the server is being overloaded.

For the time being the only things thus far that seems to have helped some people eliminate this issue is to tune the PHP configuration (such as the `max_execution_time`) and the `CURL timeout` variable.

I was wondering if anyone ever encountered this issue and if so do you have more information on why this is happening and how to fix it? So far the little information I've found hasn't been to concrete, looking for solid facts, explanations and solutions. Thanks!

Comment: I'm also using my own custom built magento Authorize.net CIM Integration and I never have this issue before. Can you ask them to log in to authorize.net and look at the time difference between the two transactions, because you would normally get "A duplicate transaction has been submitted." if same transaction is submit within ~30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your comment R.S. I've just received a response from my hosting provider (Nexcess) and they say that in the Magento exception.log there is indeed a "A duplicate transaction has been submitted". My question is how/why did that happen ?

Comment: Assuming that this is not a bug in the CIM module. If a customer checkout credit card fail because of AVS, and they quickly correct the issue and resubmit then you make get "A duplicate transaction has been submitted". See https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A425&actp=LIST

Answer (score 0):

Some visitors are very impatient.
When they click some form button and feel no action then they will double click this button.

So place some java script code to disallow second click for few seconds or place a text around button don't click this button twice.

Comment: This should be in place in magento, if he uses the standard checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this may be related to MySQL issue, let's check the log first. My case is, this MySQL error log appear near the time that the issue orders happens:

> Aborted connection 1198255 to db: '...' user: '...' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

Then I did follow this guide to make it fixed: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19139